# wordpress 3.8.1 and wp-db-abstraction

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a clean WP installation on Centos 5.8 platform using wp-db-abstraction plugin to interate with SQL Server 2008 R2 database.
I also updated PHP with version 5.4.27 where msssql module is enabled. Plus I fixed wp-db-abstraction plugin with those indications I found over Internet like fixing PATTERN variable and some stuffs like the correct path...
The matter is once I call wp-admin/install.php to install into database I get those messages on the page:

```
Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class Fields_map in
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-db-abstraction/translations/sqlsrv/fields_map.php 
on line 36

Strict Standards: Declaration of mssql_wpdb::prepare() should be compatible with 
wpdb::prepare($query, $args) in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-db-
abstraction/drivers/mssql.php on line 33 

WordPress database error: [Incorrect syntax near 'wp_users'.]
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'wp_users'
```

If I complete installation ignoring messages, then WP wouldn't work well like miss some informations that couldn't write into database or something.

Any indication would be appreciate. Even if it exists a better and newer way to communicate with SQL Server database with latest WP versions. Thanks in advance to everyone!

Cheers,
Luigi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by myself... had just to add parameters into plugin's file.

Now I have to figure out the wordpress database error

```
[Incorrect syntax near 'wpmxp_users'.] SHOW TABLES LIKE 'wp_users'
```

only... Maybe is that error related to some syntax of new PHP version?...

Comment: Solved. had to downversion to 3.5.1 the WP due to wp-db-abstraction

Comment: this error is irritating me for few days, will you please tell me exactly what you have modified in plugin's file and which one